# Avoiding port number in Liferay's assets URL

Tags: liferay

I have Apache in front and then tomcat. Problem is am getting assets url(url of JavaScript and CSS files) as https://_xxx.com:3100/ when I check in the browser console.

I want to avoid the port number, I want those assets to be served on port 443 so that the urls would be: https://_xxx.com/

I have tried setting  portal.instance.https.port=false but that didn't remove the port number.

How can I configure things in Liferay so that those assets are served over port 443?

Comment: You're tagging this "spring-portlet-mvc" but don't include any code. How do you generate those URLs when you want to use them? Note: If this is just what Liferay generates out of the box, then this is rather a configuration question, out of scope for stackoverflow. Please include code to clarify your question and to demonstrate that it's on topic.

Comment: @OlafKock I understand but this kind of url is generated out of the box in Liferay. So I thought of Liferay guys can understand and reply to it.
It will be greatly helpful if anyone can answer the above.

Comment: have you yet tried `web.server.https.port=443` and `web.server.protocol=https` when there is a webserver in front?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is rather a configuration issue, and normally, in these kind of scenarios you do not want Liferay's port to be visible at all. Please check your port properties:

```
web.server.https.port=443
web.server.http.port=80

web.server.protocol=https
```

Additionally, your proxy needs to be set up in a way that tells Liferay that it is running behind a proxy for a more complete set up:

```
web.server.forwarded.host.enabled=true
web.server.forwarded.host.header=X-Forwarded-Host

web.server.forwarded.port.enabled=true
web.server.forwarded.port.header=X-Forwarded-Port

web.server.forwarded.protocol.enabled=true
web.server.forwarded.protocol.header=X-Forwarded-Proto
```

To get an example of configuration for your apache proxy instance, you can use this link: [liferay-behind-a-reverse-proxy](https://www.e-systems.tech/docker-images/-/knowledge_base/docker-images/liferay-behind-a-reverse-proxy-1-1-1-1)